# Google Directions API - Multiple Legs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get multiple legs?

i.e If I try and get directions from the Google Directions from two different addresses it only gives me 1 leg but when I do the exact same request on Google maps it gives me 4 routes. Any ideas how I can get the four routes?

My Request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=48%20yonge%20street,%20toronto,%20ontario&destination=184%20longhouse%20street,%20woodbridge,%20ontario&key=x&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want route alternatives, not legs.

Use the [alternatives=true parameter in the request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters)